# Apache POI - How to set character spacing for XWPFRun

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I need to create an XWPFRun with character spacing expanded by 1 pt. I tried the methods `setCharacterSpacing` and `setKerning` but to no avail. I also found no code examples or documentation for either method.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me [XWPFRun.setCharacterSpacing](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setCharacterSpacing-int-) works. What one needs to know is that the measurement unit is `TWIP` - twentieths of an inch point. So 1*20 is 1 pt.

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateXWPFRunCharacterSpacing {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is sample text to compare character spacing.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is sample text to compare character spacing.");
  run.setCharacterSpacing(1*20); // measurement unit is TWIPS - twentieths of a point. So 1*20 is 1 pt.

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateXWPFRunCharacterSpacing.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```